# Is there a way I can put placeholder text in a textinput and replace the characters of the placeholder text 1 by 1 as the user is typing?

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I have a textInput with a placeholder text

```
<TextInput
  placeholder={'YYYY-MM-DD'}
  onChangeText{this.onChangeText}
/>
```

is there a way for me to replace the characters individually as the user enters input on the field so as to produce output similar to what is shown on the images below?

textInput field before user enters characters

[image: textInput field before user enters characters]

after user types in the first 2 character of the date

[image: after user types in the first 2 character of the date]

when user is done typing date

[image: when user is done typing date]

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You may try date input type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Or, if you want to make it manually, you can get/change cursor's location with `Element.selectionStart` property.

Comment: This would be a good solution if I were using react-js but I need a solution for react-native without using external libraries